# Feed input of MS-DOS interactive executable with a string value

Tags: python, perforce

p4.exe is the perforce command line tool (git/cvs/svn like tool).
I am trying to launch several ms-dos commands **'p4 resolve'** in an python script. because I have a hundred files to resolve.

However I cannot launch **'p4 resolve -m'** as I want (which automatically opens my 3-way merge tool on the conflicting files). **p4** doesn't accept the m as an executable parameter.

Instead, manually, I must do **'p4 resolve'**, then wait for the prompt to ask me for an option, and then only type **'m'** there.

Do you know in python how I could feed the input since I cannot pass the **'m'** parameter to the command line tool **p4.exe**.

For the moment I use os.system(myDosCommand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like...

```
from subprocess import Popen

resolve = Popen(["p4", "resolve"])
stdout, stderr = resolve.communicate("m")
```

Comment: i've chosen yours as the good answer. However, I do have read that "from X import Y" is not the most pythonic way of importing ;-)

Comment: @StephaneRolland: where did you read that? PEP8 makes no problem of it. You must be thinking of `from X import *`, which I would never write.

Comment: oh, I have generalized too much ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Use the shell option command with [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)

```
import subprocess

retcode = subprocess.call(["p4", "resolve", "-m"], shell=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want Perforce to auto-merge all pending integrations:

```
p4 resolve -am
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Cygwin you can try [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html), a pure Python version of the TCL utility [expect](http://techi2teach.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-get-python-pexpect-module-on.html).

Adapted from the documentation:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('p4 resolve')
child.expect('Some string that p4 resolve presents')
child.sendline('m')
```

I don't know of any options not using Cygwin and I found [a post](http://techi2teach.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-get-python-pexpect-module-on.html) about installing Cygwin just to get pexpect to work, so perhaps there isn't a better alternative.

Comment: It's not supposed to work on Windows. But it does work on Cygwin, I added a note about that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried merely piping the input to the command?

In cmd.exe:

C:\> echo m | p4 resolve